# Splitting string with pipe character ("|")

Tags: java, regex

I'm not able to split values from this string:

`"Food 1 | Service 3 | Atmosphere 3 | Value for money 1 "`

Here's my current code:

```
String rat_values = "Food 1 | Service 3 | Atmosphere 3 | Value for money 1 ";
String[] value_split = rat_values.split("|");
```

#### Output

> [, F, o, o, d,  , 1,  , |,  , S, e, r, v, i, c, e,  , 3,  , |,  , A, t, m, o, s, p, h, e, r, e,  , 3,  , |,  , V, a, l, u, e,  , f, o, r,  , m, o, n, e, y,  , 1,  ]

#### Expected output

> Food 1
>   Service 3
>   Atmosphere 3
>   Value for money 1

Answer (score 690, accepted):

`|` is a metacharacter in regex.  You'd need to escape it:

```
String[] value_split = rat_values.split("\\|");
```

Comment: It took me like 15 minutes to track this down as I was mysteriously getting the same problem and thought it was related to my newbie (for java 8) use of `Array.AsList` or `Arrays.stream` - thanks devnull!

Comment: This is the correct answer technically but the answer by Prateek is far more complete.

Comment: @devnull - This does fails to pick last element if we have value as empty.

e.g. If we have A||B|C|| -> It will give us array{A,"",B,C} while it should be {A,"",B,C,"",""}

Answer (score 101):

### Using Pattern.quote()

```
String[] value_split = rat_values.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rat_values.split(Pattern.quote("|")))); //(FOR GETTING OUTPUT)
```

### Using Escape characters(for metacharacters)

```
String[] value_split = rat_values.split("\\|");
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rat_values.split("\\|"))); //(FOR GETTING OUTPUT)
```

### Using StringTokenizer(For avoiding regular expression issues)

```
public static String[] splitUsingTokenizer(String Subject, String Delimiters) 
{
     StringTokenizer StrTkn = new StringTokenizer(Subject, Delimiters);
     ArrayList<String> ArrLis = new ArrayList<String>(Subject.length());
     while(StrTkn.hasMoreTokens())
     {
       ArrLis.add(StrTkn.nextToken());
     }
     return ArrLis.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

### Using Pattern class(java.util.regex.Pattern)

```
Arrays.asList(Pattern.compile("\\|").split(rat_values))
//System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Pattern.compile("\\|").split(rat_values))); //(FOR GETTING OUTPUT)
```

### Output

```
[Food 1 ,  Service 3 ,  Atmosphere 3 ,  Value for money 1 ]
```

Comment: For the second version, would you call it as `splitUsingTokenizer("Food 1 | Service 3 | Atmosphere 3 | Value for money 1 ", "|")` ?

Answer (score 23):

Or.. [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] value_split = rat_values.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

This is happening because [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) accepts a *regex*:

`|` has a [special meaning in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

`quote` will return a String representation for the *regex*.

Comment: Upvoted for actually doing RCA

Answer (score 15):

split takes regex as a parameter.`|` has special meaning in regex.. use `\\|` instead of `|` to escape it.

Answer (score 5):

```
String rat_values = "Food 1 | Service 3 | Atmosphere 3 | Value for money 1 ";
    String[] value_split = rat_values.split("\\|");
    for (String string : value_split) {

        System.out.println(string);

    }
```