# Map-Reduce Program : Mapper not behaving as expected

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Friends,

I am new to Map-Reduce and trying my hand with one example which only executes a Mapper; but the output is strange and not expected. Please help me finding, if I am missing something here:

Code part:

**Imports:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
```

**Driver Program**

```
Job job = new Job(conf,"SampleProgram");
job.setJarByClass(SampleMR.class);     // class that contains mapper and reducer
job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);    // reducer class

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/tmp/"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/tmp/out"));  // adjust directories as required

job.submit();

boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
if (!b) {
    throw new IOException("error with job!");
}
```

**Mapper Program**

```
public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>  {
@Override
        public void map(LongWritable idx , Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split("|");
            String keyPrefix = tokens[0] + tokens[1];
            context.write(new Text(keyPrefix), value);
        }
    }
```

There is a reducer phase as well, but I have set reducer to 0 to debug the issue. Here the mapper is not behaving correctly.

**For the Input**

> 379782759851005|ABCDEFG|name:YOLO|top:44.7|avgtop:19.2

**The expected Map output is**

> 379782759851005ABCDEFG  *[Blank Space]* 379782759851005|ABCDEFG|name:YOLO|top:44.7|avgtop:19.2

**Output my Mapper**

> **3**   *[Blank Space]* 379782759851005|ABCDEFG|name:YOLO|top:44.7|avgtop:19.2

Looks like, the Key is printing just first letter of the expected output. Same is happening with value as well, if I try to add `tokens[4]` as value to the context. Looks like there is something happening while spliting the string.
Any Insight, what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the pipe character. see the link below:

[Splitting string with pipe character ("|")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524642/splitting-string-with-pipe-character)

Comment: Ohh.. I missed this point so badly, just focusing on if Hadoop MR is doing something funky. Thank you for pointing this issue.