# Java split string by "^|^"

Tags: java, regex

I have a sample data following:

```
***^|^100^|^101^|^102^|^103^|^104^|^
```

I wish to split by "^|^" so the result will be:

```
***
100
101
102
103
104
```

Below is my sample code, but failed to obtain expected result,am i misunderstood the split pattern?

```
String a = "***^|^100^|^101^|^102^|^103^|^104^|^105^|^106^|^107^|^108^|^";
String [] split ;

split = a.split("^|^");
for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
{
        System.out.println(split[i]);
}
```

Comment: `split = a.split("\\^\\|\\^");` use this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524642/splitting-string-with-pipe-character

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `^` and `|` are special-chatacters you need to escape them.

```
split = a.split("\\^\\|\\^");
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `Pattern.quote()` to treat all meta characters as String literals / Literal pattern. `^` , `|` have special meaning in regex.

This should work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "***^|^100^|^101^|^102^|^103^|^104^|^";
    String pattern = Pattern.quote("^|^");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(pattern)));

}
```

O/P :

```
[***, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104]
```

Comment: I had no idea about Pattern.  Thanks looks awesome.

Comment: That looks much nicer than the usual backslash frenzy. Still, I wished there was a split method that takes a separator string, not a regex.

Comment: @Thilo - Ya. That would have made things much simpler :)

Comment: and if you use that same pattern in more than one place, you can declare it once for all to use `public static final Pattern HAT_PIPE_HAT = Pattern.quote("^|^")`

Comment: @Thilo - `Pattern.quote()` returns a `String`. But Yes, you are right, creation of Patterns is costly :)

Comment: I was thinking more about readibility. I don't think it's  that costly.   But one could take it one step further and do `static final Pattern HAT_PIPE_HAT = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("^|^"))` which gives `HAT_PIPE_HAT.split(theString)`.

Comment: @Thilo - Yep. Making patterns `static` and `final` improve readability as well as *reusability* :)

Answer (score -2):

Please check this

```
String str = "***^|^100^|^101^|^102^|^103^|^104^|^";
String arr[] = str.split("\\^\\|\\^");
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

Comment: what's different in this answer from Uma?