# Split a string in java escaping whitespace and use the delimilter

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string in the form `Final Test|0`.

I wanted the string to be split into 2

```
[0] = Final Test
[1] = 0
```

Below is the code i was working on:

```
String value = "Final Test|0";
String[] mainValues = value .split(" | ");
```

Using the above code i got

```
[Final, Test|0]
```

Even tried doing this

```
  String value = "Final Test|0";
  String[] mainValues = value .split("|");
```

Also when i tried escaping the white space using regex i got

```
F,i,n,a,l,,T,e,s,t,|,0
```

Please guide.

Comment: The spaces before the pipe make it mean: split space OR space in regex...

Comment: I tried i got this output F, i, n, a, l,  , T, e, s, t, |, 0

Comment: The problem is that | is for OR in RegEx. You must escape it: `\\|`

Comment: give a try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524642/splitting-string-with-pipe-character)

Comment: @AndrewLi That helped :) Thaanks mate

Comment: Thanks Imran...:)