# Split a string into substring using '|' character

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to split a string as follows, "Client|Role". My regex is "|".

I expected two substrings as "Client" and "Role", but what I get is each and every character as a substring including the character in my regex. Why I am getting like this? Please help, Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows,

```
String output = "Client|Role";
String values[] = output.split("|");
```

Comment: Can you please mention the duplicate question link. @Wiktor Stribizew

Comment: Kishore, just reload this page and it should appear ontop of your question (in a yellow box).

Comment: @Kishore [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796174/3832970) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21524670/3832970) answers summing up to 837 upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

You can split like this..

```
String b = "Client|Role";       
String[] elements = b.split("\\|");
```